# Select all inputs using value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select all inputs (textbox) in my form which have required class and have no value. So I am using:

```
$('input[value=""]', '.required')
```

My problem is even when the user enters a value in the textbox, the val() returns that value, but value is still empty and so my above jquery still selects all the inputs which were previously empty, which it should not. How do i select all inputs whose val is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value attribute` and `value property` of an input are not the same after a user edits it.

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and check the value property ... something like:

```
var $empties = $('input[required]').filter(function(){
   return !this.value;
}).doSomething();

if(!$empties.length){
   // process submit
}else{
   // prevent submit
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, catch every input with `required` attribute, then look for inputs without value.

```js
$('input[required=""]').each(function(){
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    console.log(this);
    //logic
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input required>
<input required>
<input required value='x'>
<input value='y'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still use jquery's val() function

```
var required_inputs = [];
$('input.required').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == "") {
        required_inputs.push($this);
    }
})
```

That way you have an array of required input elements which are empty. You could execute that function eg. on blur of each such input and then do with those elements whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` to get all the inputs with `val()` empty, by checking each one's value in return statement.

```js
$("#getInputs").click(function() {
  var arr = $('input').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).val() == '');
  });
  console.log(arr)
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<button id="getInputs">Get</button>
```

Comment: `val()` will never return `null`

Comment: What I meant is empty in the literal sense.

Comment: fine...but that's not the same as `null`

Answer (score -1):

You can select like this,

**HTML**

```
<input class="required"  />
<input class="required"  />
<input class="required" value='x'>
<input value='y'>
```

**JS**

```
 $("input:not([value]).required, input[value=''].required")
```

Thanks

Comment: doesn't account for user input